# unable to access web UI of oozie from Ambari in HDI 3.6 spark HDInsight cluster

Tags: azure, oozie, azure-hdinsight, ambari

I have set up the HDI 3.6 spark 2.1.0 HDInsight cluster.

Now I need to submit a spark job using oozie workflow,for doing this I need to configure the workflow.xml using Ambari.

The problem arises when accessing oozie webUI from Ambari as below:

[image]

while click on Oozie web UI I am getting the following error for loading the url:
https://samplecluster.azurehdinsight.net/da/host/hn0-cloudo.fabtnv3ti3juvluair5dbgfudc.hx.internal.cloudapp.net/port/11000/oozie?user.name=sathyaraj

error:

```
{
  "status": 404,
  "message": "Not Found"
}
```

Comment: Spark2 action in hdp seems still in preview. Did you able to make ut work? I would love to know if you could.

Comment: @AyanGuha through ssh tunneling we can able to access this oozie web UI. Please refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-linux-ambari-ssh-tunnel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the Oozie Web UI, use the following steps:

1. Create an SSH tunnel to the HDInsight cluster. For information, see the [Use SSH Tunneling with HDInsight document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-linux-ambari-ssh-tunnel).
2. Once a tunnel has been created, open the Ambari web UI in your web browser. The URI for the Ambari site is https://CLUSTERNAME.azurehdinsight.net. Replace CLUSTERNAME with the name of your Linux-based HDInsight cluster.
3. From the left side of the page, select **Oozie**, then **Quick Links**, and finally **Oozie Web UI**.

For more details, refer “[Oozie Web UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-use-oozie-linux-mac#oozie-web-ui)”.

Comment: Thanks, but why not directly we can able to access these oozie web UI, without setting up ssh tunneling in ubuntu machine.

Comment: Several of the menus in Ambari only work through an SSH tunnel. These menus(EX: OOZIE) rely on web sites and services running on other node types, such as worker nodes. Often, these web sites are not secured, so it is not safe to directly expose them on the internet.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable information, its helped me alot.